# Number of connected graphs that can be globally embedded in a $2$-d triangular lattice with $n$ verticies of degree$\geq 2$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I've been playing a board game where the game board is constructed by players by placing a number of hexagonal tiles adjacent to each other along an edge.  The only rules when making the board is that by the end each tile must be adjacent to at least two other tiles and tiles can't go on top of other tiles.  In the game players move their playing piece from one tile to an adjacent tile and take actions, the tiles never move.  Since this game allows players to design their own maps I was wondering how many different maps are possible from the perspective of affecting gameplay (i.e. the graph of the map is different).

I tried hand counting the first few values and, counting from $n=3$ got: $1,1,2,6,13$, but didn't find any sequences on OEIS that looked promising for solving this.  I'm most interested in finding the answers for $n=13$ and $n=24$ (the number of tiles in variants the game).

I'd be grateful for any tips on where to look or how to possibly make a program to count these, especially how to represent a graph and determine if two graphs are the same.

Comment: Would this be the number of planar connected graphs with all vertices of degrees between two and six?

Comment: On second thought I don't think it is because you could have a graph of that description that has one hexagon inside another with one connection between each vertex of both, which isn't allowed here.

Comment: I think the $n=5$ value is $1$; rotation will bring the two options for adding a point to $n=4$ into alignment.

Comment: But you can also add two points to n=3 to make a bowtie shape